# Facebook.SDK not been initialized error in Expo Management App and expo/auth/session

Tags: react-native, expo, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have an expo managed app that when I run in the production build, I getting the following error.

**The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() first.**

So I added **Facebook.initializeAsync('MyAppId')** to the App.js file and I added the **facebookAutoInitEnabled: true** in the app.json file. It is a expo managed app, so I don't have access to the android native files before build time. Also, the app works for Facebook login when using the app in a simulator.

I followed this tutorial to setup Facebook login, in my app: https://derk-jan.com/2020/05/expo-facebook-login

Can somebody tell me how to properly make sure the Facebook SDK is initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the

facebookAutoInitEnabled: true
and
facebookAppId: 'MyFacebookAppId'

set in the app.json